# Php Switch Case URL Issue (Won't Load)

Tags: php, .htaccess, loading

I have pretty basic Switch Case DirectoryIndex default php file:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['open'])
{
    default: include("TheSite-Entrance.php"); break;
    case 'Home': include("pages/home.php"); break;
    case 'About Us': include("pages/about.php"); break;
    case 'Contact': include("pages/contact.php"); break;
}
?>
```

Now, for example, when I click the `<A href="/?open=Home">Home</A>` it takes me normally to my Home page, BUT when I click on any link on the Home page, nothing happens for like 10 seconds, and then the clicked link starts to load, it first displays completely blank (white) page with a (random?) number in the upper left corner while the clicked link is still loading and loading... It keeps loading continually until I select the clicked link in the URL bar and hit Enter, only then the page starts loading normally. Also, this is my .htaccess file, if the problem might be caused by it:

```
DirectoryIndex TheSite.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.net/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.net/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: What a nasty way to route your website... using GET

Comment: without .htacces works the same ? take a look if you are using  flush control obj or  overloading routines.

Comment: @QuijoteShin Without the .htaccess, it loads the site like https://www.othersite.net/example.net... Also blank page.

Comment: @QuijoteShin. Bravo! Thank you. It was overloading.

Comment: cool you found it!